# issues with openssl and getting correct values

Tags: linux, bash, unix, hash, openssl

I seem to be having an issue with getting the correct value of openssl command when it is hashed.  Here is what I have for code.

```
IFS=","

while read -ra line;
do
   if [ "${line[1]}" != "" ]; then
        echo -n "${line[*]},"; echo -n "${line[1]}" | openssl dgst -sha1 | sed 's/^.* //' ;
   else
        if [ "${line[1]}" == "" ]; then
            echo "${line[*]}, Hash Value: None";
        fi
   fi
done
```

Here is the input of the second column in the text file, which is "${line[1]}" in the code.

```
"1376051635"
```

This is how I am running the command:

```
./orange.sh < "C:\Documents and Settings\562359\Desktop\Analytics\persons\persons.txt"
```

Output to screen is this:

```
"524786870","1376051635",2483a818fac3e5214697f1ed76d92e2f54d4a277
```

the third column is the hashed value of the second column but it is not correct.  When I run this command

```
echo -n "1376051635" | openssl dgst -sha1
```

My output is:

```
(stdin)= f8d822c6b46a2eb4e35bb4d76b8ce2e336d541e8
```

which is the correct hash value.  Why is this not working how it should be working?  It seems that the code is right but the hash value is being outputted completely different than what it should be.  Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're including the double quote signs that's why you're getting a different value.

You could try this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=","

while read -ra line; do
    if [[ -n ${line[1]} ]]; then
        second_value=${line[1]#\"} second_value=${second_value%\"}
        hash_value=$(echo -n "$second_value" | openssl dgst -sha1 | sed 's/^.* //')
        echo "${line[*]},${hash_value}"  ## Or should ${hashvalue} be surrounded by quotes?: \"${hash_value}\"
    else
        echo "${line[*]}, Hash Value: None"
    fi
done
```

Note: If you're planning to replace the previous hash value, use this line instead:

```
        echo "${line[*]:0:2},${hash_value}"
```

Comment: You mean like this: `"${line[1]}"?`  Without the double quotes produces same result

Comment: @Beardy When reading from a file, the value took from the second column would include the double quotes surrounding it. Doing something like `echo "${line[1]}"` would print `"123456789"` which includes the quotes whereas a quoted literal string e.g. `echo "123456789"` would only print `123456789`.

Comment: I see what you are saying.  I've tried both ways with the input file and it seems to be producing the same result.  I'm going to try out what you put for code and see if I can get the correct results.  Stay tuned

Comment: Seems to be going right to the else statement, rendering "Hash Value: None"

Comment: That's odd. With your example `"524786870","1376051635",2483a818fac3e5214697f1ed76d92e2f54d4a277` it works fine with me. Please try to execute the script with `bash script.sh < input` instead. Also make sure it's not copied in CRLF format. When I ran my script I got `"524786870","1376051635",f8d822c6b46a2eb4e35bb4d76b8ce2e336d541e8`.

Comment: Dude that was it! combination of removing quotes and also converting to unix type.  Results are now printing accordingly!  Thanks man :)